copy data from sheet to another sheet in excel based on certain criteria

3 sheets


invoice
recofinv
inctype
in the record of invoice i am writing a header, inv# from cell h3,inv date = cell h4, customer ="cell C8 and total amount of inv I24, with other information from a cell in invoice called category.


i also want to write the following details to another sheet called "inctype".


invnr = h3   date = h4    customer = c8   code = b14     qty=h14    itemamt=i14
each line entry for line 14 to 22 each on its own line
the problem with this is it writes only line 14 and ignore lines 15-22 in the inctype sheet

Here is my code
Sub CreateNewInvoiceAndEmail()
    Dim invno As Long
    Dim wsInvoice As Worksheet
    Dim wsRecordOfInvoices As Worksheet
    Dim wsInctype As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowInvoice As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim category As String
    Dim amount As Double
    Dim categoryColumn As Long
    Dim existingRow As Range
    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim existingAmount As Double
    Dim path As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim incTypeRow As Long ' Counter for rows in inctype sheet
    Dim invRow As Long ' Counter for rows in Invoice sheet
    
    ' Set references to the Invoice, Record of Invoices, and Inctype sheets
    Set wsInvoice = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice") ' Update with your actual sheet name
    Set wsRecordOfInvoices = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RecOfInv") ' Update with your actual sheet name
    Set wsInctype = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("inctype") ' Update with your actual sheet name
    
    invno = wsInvoice.Range("H3").Value
    lastRowInvoice = wsInvoice.Cells(wsInvoice.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Determine the next available row in Inctype sheet
    incTypeRow = wsInctype.Cells(wsInctype.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    ' Loop through each row in Invoice sheet to update Record of Invoices and Inctype
    For invRow = 14 To lastRowInvoice ' Rows 14 to the last used row in Invoice sheet
        category = wsInvoice.Cells(invRow, "F").Value
        amount = wsInvoice.Cells(invRow, "I").Value
        
        Debug.Print "Category to match: " & category
        
        ' Find the column number in Record of Invoices for the category
        On Error Resume Next
        categoryColumn = WorksheetFunction.Match(category, wsRecordOfInvoices.Rows(1), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        Debug.Print "Category column: " & categoryColumn
        
        If categoryColumn > 0 Then
            ' Check if there's already an entry for this category in Record of Invoices
            Set existingRow = wsRecordOfInvoices.Columns("A").Find(What:=invno, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            
            If existingRow Is Nothing Then
                ' Write the invoice details to Record of Invoices
                nextRow = wsRecordOfInvoices.Cells(wsRecordOfInvoices.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                wsRecordOfInvoices.Cells(nextRow, "A").Value = invno
                wsRecordOfInvoices.Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = wsInvoice.Range("C8").Value ' Customer Name from C8 in Invoice sheet
                wsRecordOfInvoices.Cells(nextRow, categoryColumn).Value = amount ' Write amount to category column
                wsRecordOfInvoices.Cells(nextRow, "C").Value = wsInvoice.Range("H24").Value ' Total Amount
                wsRecordOfInvoices.Cells(nextRow, "D").Value = wsInvoice.Range("H4").Value ' Date Issued
                wsRecordOfInvoices.Cells(nextRow, "E").Value = wsInvoice.Range("H4").Value + wsInvoice.Range("H5").Value ' Date Due
                
                ' Save the invoice as PDF
                path = "G:\My Drive\Nampol\Finance\Invoices 2024\"
                fname = invno & " - " & wsInvoice.Range("C8").Value & ".pdf"
                wsInvoice.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, Filename:=path & fname
                ' Save the PDF path as hyperlink in column 7 of Record of Invoices
                wsRecordOfInvoices.Cells(nextRow, "G").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wsRecordOfInvoices.Cells(nextRow, "G"), Address:=path & fname, TextToDisplay:=fname
                
                ' Insert data into Inctype sheet
                
                wsInctype.Cells(incTypeRow, "A").Value = invno
                wsInctype.Cells(incTypeRow, "B").Value = wsInvoice.Range("H4").Offset(invRow - 14, 0).Value ' Date from H14, H15, ...
                wsInctype.Cells(incTypeRow, "C").Value = wsInvoice.Range("C8").Value ' Customer Name
                wsInctype.Cells(incTypeRow, "D").Value = wsInvoice.Cells(invRow, "B").Value ' Code from B14, B15, ...
                wsInctype.Cells(incTypeRow, "E").Value = wsInvoice.Cells(invRow, "I").Value ' Item Amount from I14, I15, ...
                wsInctype.Cells(incTypeRow, "F").Value = wsInvoice.Cells(invRow, "H").Value ' Qty from H14, H15, ...
                
                ' Increment incTypeRow for the next row in Inctype sheet
                incTypeRow = incTypeRow + 1
            Else
                ' If an entry already exists, update the amount for the category
                existingAmount = existingRow.Offset(0, categoryColumn - 1).Value ' Offset to the category column
                
                ' Sum existing amount with new amount for the category
                existingRow.Offset(0, categoryColumn - 1).Value = existingAmount + amount
            End If
        Else
            ' Handle case where category is not found
            MsgBox "Category '" & category & "' not found in Record of Invoices."
        End If
    Next invRow
    
    ' Send email with PDF attachment
    ' Code for sending email goes here...
    
    MsgBox "Next Invoice # is " & invno + 1
    
    ' Update the invoice number for the next invoice
    wsInvoice.Range("H3").Value = invno + 1
    
    ' Clear specific ranges in the Invoice sheet
    Range("C8:F8,B14:B22,F14:G22,H14:H22").ClearContents
    
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub


Add Debug.Print lastRowInvoice before For loop to check its value in Immedate Window. Debug.Print "Category to match: " & category - Have your seen all ouput (14~22) in Immedate Window?
